# JPQL: The state field path cannot be resolved to a valid type

Tags: jpql

I can't make this query work:

```
Query query = eManager.createQuery("select c FROM News c WHERE c.NEWSID = :id",News.class);
        return (News)query.setParameter("id", newsId).getSingleResult();
```

and I got this exception:

```
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select c FROM News c WHERE c.NEWSID = :id]. 
[27, 35] The state field path 'c.NEWSID' cannot be resolved to a valid type.] with root cause
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [select c FROM News c WHERE c.NEWSID = :id].
```

Why does it happen? 
:id and named parameter are identical

**EDIT:** 
my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="NEWS")
public class News implements Serializable{

    @Id 
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "news_seq_gen", sequenceName = "news_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "news_seq_gen")
    private int newsId;
    private String newsTitle;
    private String newsBrief;
    private String newsContent;
    private Date newsDate;
    @Transient
    private boolean selected=false;

//constructor and getters and setters
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That happens because `News` entity does not have persistent attribute named `NEWSID`. Names of the persistent attributes are case sensitive in JPQL queries and those should be written with exactly same case as they appear in entity.

Because entity have persistent attribute named `newsId`, that should also be used in query instead of `NEWSID`:

```
select c FROM News c WHERE c.newsId = :id
```

Comment: hm but it actually does: here is my entity:

Comment: Name of the parameter is not the problem - name of the persistent attribute is. In entity there is attribute named newsId, same should be used in query, as follows: WHERE c.newsId (at the moment there is NEWSID in query).

Comment: hm now i have classcast exception Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/strts-spring-hbnt] threw exception [java.lang.ClassCastException: com.epam.testapp.domain.News cannot be cast to com.epam.testapp.domain.News] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.epam.testapp.domain.News cannot be cast to com.epam.testapp.domain.News

Comment: ok problem resolved i changed ClassLoader in context.xml  into TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader

Answer (score 1):

entity have persistent attribute named newsId.but in query you have used NEWSID . try with this

```
select c FROM News c WHERE c.newsId = :id
```

Answer (score -1):

My entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_PERSON_INFO")
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer user_id;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

my query is (JPQL):

```
String queryName = "from Person p where p.user_id = :user_id";
```

so I use it like this:

```
        javax.persistence.Query query = em.createQuery(queryName);
        query.setParameter("user_id", userId);

        try {
            obj = query.getSingleResult();
        }
        catch (javax.persistence.NoResultException nre) {
            logger.error("javax.persistence.NoResultException: " + nre.getMessage());
        }
        catch (javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException nure) {
            logger.error("javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: " + nure.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (obj == null) {
            System.out.println("obj is null!");
            return null;
        }

        Person person = (Person) obj;
```

It's work ;-)