# Filter is not working on JPQL query of one to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have created following classes i.e. Teacher and Student.

## JAVA Code: Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")

public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "cmp_id")
    private String cmpId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacherid", referencedColumnName = "teacherid")
    private Teacher teacher;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "typeid", referencedColumnName = "typeid")
    private Type type;
}
```

## JAVA Code: Teacher

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Teacher")
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "teacherid")
    private String teacherid;

    @Column(name = "teachername")
    private String teachername;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Teacher", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("cmpSequence ASC")
    private List<Student> std;
}
```

## JAVA Code: Type

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Type")
public class Type{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "typeid")
    private Integer typeid;

    @Column(name = "uitype")
    private String uitype;    
}
```

Teacher is parent class and Student is child class.I want all teachers and their student with filter typeid is 1 but it does not work.

## Following is the JPQL query which I created:

`SELECT teacher FROM Teacher teacher WHERE  teacher.std.typeid = 1`

## Its gives me following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while
>   creating a query in EntityManager:  Exception Description: Problem
>   compiling query.The state field path 'teacher.std.typeid' cannot be
>   resolved to a valid type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPQL: The state field path cannot be resolved to a valid type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056847/jpql-the-state-field-path-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-valid-type)

Comment: because your JPQL is nonsense. You cannot refer to multi-valued fields in a WHERE clause navigating through them, you have to do explicit JOINs. But then any basic JPA documentation would include this

Answer (score 3):

Your query is wrong. You have `Teacher` which has std (`Student`), std has type (`Type`) and type has typeid field. So your query should looks like following:

```
SELECT teacher FROM Teacher teacher 
JOIN FETCH teacher.std AS s 
INNER JOIN s.type as t 
WHERE t.typeid = 1
```

Comment: teacher.students AS s WHERE s.type.typeid = 1 in ur query students is Class name or obj

Comment: sorry, std instead of students

Comment: Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling query. The state field path 's.type.typeid' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

Comment: One more attempt, please try